# Scala: Will None.method result in error

Tags: scala

Let us say a method `method1("abc")` returns `Some()`.
What happens when the return value of `method1("abc")` is `None` and I perform `method1("abc").method` on it?

I have'nt installed scala nor intend to anytime soon. I was browsing through some blogs on scala and this question popped up. Web search did not give concrete answers.

Comment: Could you please make more practice before asking basic question ...

Comment: @Pavel As I said, I don't intend to install scala. I am not finding an answer online after reading through for an hour. I did not expect a downvote for a curious query!!

Comment: If you are not going to install scala, answers to this question aren't likely to be useful to you.

Comment: @Dima I am sorry but I have to disagree. From my perspective it would help me in understanding the core principles driving scala which in turn will let me attain new concepts and design philosophies in programming which I find very valuable.

Comment: If you are interested in concepts and design principles, read a book about concepts and design principles. Asking basic syntax questions on SO without any intention on using that syntax doesn't get you any closer to that goal.

Comment: Not going to take this discussion any further. Got the answer I needed. Cheers!!

Comment: What, exactly, is unclear about the list of methods in the documentation of `Some`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens when the return value of method1("abc") is None and I
>   perform method1("abc").method on it

You cant. If your return type is an `Option[String]`, then you're not actually dealing with `String`, but one inside a *container*. This means that `String` methods won't be visible to you. In order to go *inside* the container, you'll need to use methods on `Option[T]` which do so, like `map`:

```
def foo(): Option[String] = ???

val res: Option[String] = foo()
val length: Option[Int] = res.map(str => str.length)
```

`Option.map` is aware of the fact that the option may be `None`. In such a case, the function inside the `map` method will not execute, but you see that these methods always keep us inside the context of the container.

Answer (score 1):

`None` is not `null`.  It is a normal object and method call won't cause `NullPointerException`.  This is one of the benefits of using Option instead of just making things null.

The only method that would cause an exception is `get` which is an unsafe method to extract the value from an option which should only be used if you are absolutely sure you have a Some.  Even then Option.get is not the most idiomatic.